# Authentication for Apache Flink REST API

Tags: apache-flink

Is there any way to restrict access to the REST API provided by Apache Flink, e.g. using Basic Auth, Api-Key, etc.?

I refer to the "Monitoring REST API" (which is confusingly not only monitoring but also job control).

Answer (score 0):

One solution others have used is to put nginx in front of the Flink REST API as a secure proxy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a FLIP about custom netty handlers (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=184616200) that comes with sample use cases such as authentication.

For instance, basic auth = https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23273 (https://github.com/cloudera/flink-basic-auth-handler)